# Variable problem on ipython console of python 3 in spyder

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, variables, scope, spyder

Recently I'm considering using mainly python 3 although I have used python 2.7 so far.
But I encountered variable problem on python 3 as follows.

For example, the below code properly works in python 2.

```
#print a 
a=1
```

I run the code named `test.py` many times on ipython console (python 2.7.16) in spyder 3.3.6.
After the first run, I remove `#` in the first line.
Then, ipython console outputs `1` which is `a`'s value.

However, when I run the above code (the first line is replaced by `#print(a)`) similar to the above on ipython console (python 3.7.6) in spyder 4.0.1, ipython console outputs an error message,
`NameError: name 'a' is not defined`.
When I input `a` in the ipython console, the console outputs `1`.

Can I do the same thing in my python 3 environment as I do in python 2?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a setting when running the script called "Run in console's namespace instead of an empty one".
If you tick that box it keeps the variables in the namespace.